# Gulp dest not working in Windows7

Tags: node.js, windows-7, gulp

**The setup**

I've followed [this tutorial](http://sixrevisions.com/web-performance/improve-website-speed) for installing Gulp and configuring a gulpfile.js to concatenate and minify JavaScript files. I am using a Windows7 machine. When I run the `gulp` command, I get this output:

[image: Gulpfile runs without error]

There are no errors, but [`gulp.dest()`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpdestpath-options) doesn't create the expected "dist/js/MATRIX.min.js".

Here is my gulpfile:

```
/* based on http://sixrevisions.com/web-performance/improve-website-speed/ */

var gulp = require('gulp');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concatcss = require('gulp-concat-css');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    svgmin = require('gulp-svgmin');


//gulp.task('default', ['css', 'js', 'img', 'svg', 'html'], function () {});
gulp.task('default', ['js'], function () {});

// CSS concatenation + minification task
gulp.task('css', function() {
  return gulp.src('sourcecode/css/*.css')
    .pipe(concatcss('semeano.min.css'))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});

// JS linting + minification + concatenation task
gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'sourcecode/js/agregate/modernizr.custom.08680.min.js',
        'sourcecode/js/agregate/jquery.js',
        'sourcecode/js/agregate/jquery-ui.js',
        'sourcecode/js/agregate/bootstrap.js',
        'sourcecode/js/agregate/jquery.dataTables.js',
        'sourcecode/js/agregate/dataTables.tableTools.js',
        'sourcecode/js/agregate/ZeroClipboard.js',
        'sourcecode/js/agregate/DT_bootstrap.js',
        'sourcecode/js/agregate/MATRIX_main.js'
    ])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter("default"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('MATRIX.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

// Image optimization task
gulp.task('img', function () {
  return gulp.src('sourcecode/img/*.*')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'));
});

// SVG optimization task
gulp.task('svg', function () {
  return gulp.src('sourcecode/svg/*.svg')
    .pipe(svgmin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/svg'));
});
```

**What I've tried**

Figuring "I know how to do things", I did some research and came across [this "Gulp suddenly not working anymore after npm update" issue](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/800), so I tried [this suggestion](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/800#issuecomment-65060976):

1. `Run: "npm install glob@4.2.2"` //no problem
2. `Run: "npm install"` //now I get a bunch of errors:

[image: A bunch of errors after the 'fix']

**What do I need to do at this point to get this working in my Windows environment?**

Comment: you need to run `npm init`, have you done that?

Comment: @entre I have now...but no change in behavior. I have also tried `npm install glob@4.3.1`, since that version is supposed to be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the first screenshot and your code snippet, it looks like `gulp.src()` isn't finding the files you want to process. Check to see if you've got any typos like ag**g**regate?

As for that github issue, it refers to an old version of gulp. Be sure you're using the latest version of gulp `3.9.0`.

Comment: How do I make sure I'm using the latest version of Gulp?

Comment: `gulp -v` will display the version installed on your machine

Comment: "From looking at the first screenshot"... your guess is based on how quickly it finished "js" step? Can gulp, or any of its methods, log with greater verbosity?

Comment: `gulp -v`: I am using `CLI version 3.9.0` and `Local version 3.9.0`

Comment: Yeah, when using `ugligy()` or `jshint()` on large files like jquery, the task is going to at least take a couple of seconds to complete. I don't think gulp can be any clearer when these types of errors errors occur.

Comment: I'd suspect the src paths might not be correct, Does the gulp file indeed located in sourcecode parent folder?